# Getting Access Denied while accessing s3 from node js lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I am getting access denied errors while uploading file from lambda to s3 bucket Below are the settings for the bucket and the role.
S3 Bucket permission

```
      "Version": "2008-10-17",
      "Id": "PolicyForDevelopment",
      "Statement": [
          {
              "Sid": "BucketAccess",
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                  "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AccountA:role/service-role/lambda-execute"
              },
              "Action": [
                  "s3:PutObject",
                  "s3:GetObject",
                  "s3:DeleteObject"
              ],
              "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test/*"
          }
      ]
  }
```

Role Permission set to access S3

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "cloudwatch:*",
                "logs:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
  }
```

I am using nodejs lambda  and don't want to put access details in s3 functions and provide the access from lambda function only to put the objects to the s3 buckets.

```
let s3 = new AWS.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });
        const params = {
                Bucket: `test`,
                Key: `test.pdf`,
                Body: base64data,
                ACL: 'public-read'
        };
        let s3Response = await s3.upload(params).promise();
....
```

I followed the link https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-execution-role-s3-bucket/ & https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/access-denied-lambda-s3-bucket/

Comment: Does your bucket or object use kms encryption?

Comment: FYI, If the "Role Permission" is showing the permissions you have assigned to the IAM Role that is attached to the AWS Lambda function, then those permissions are sufficient for granting access to any S3 buckets in the same account. There is **no need for the bucket policy** since the role already has the necessary permissions. (In fact, granting `s3:*` is not good from a security perspective. It is effectively giving the AWS Lambda function permission to do _anything_ in S3, including deleting all your buckets and objects!)